# Can't find quarterly report for NOKIA?

Tags: stocks, sec

I went to this website here:

https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html

I then typed in NOKIA because I wanted to find their quarterly report.  I was able to get to this page:

https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000924613&owner=exclude&count=40&hidefilings=0

However, I don't see any quarterly reports for financials there.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Where should I go to see official filings of financials?

---

I do see NOK listed in the USA on the NYSE.  So because they are listed in USA, doesn't that mean they need to submit their financials to SEC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nokia is a Finnish company. You may not be able to find its quarterly report using tools intended for US stocks.

You can find all relevant reporting here, on Nokia web site: https://www.nokia.com/about-us/investors/reports-filings/

In particular, as a Finnish company, the most significant reports are annual reports, not quarterly reports. You may be interested in the [annual report 2018](https://www.nokia.com/system/files/2019-05/ec1042891_nokia_20f18.pdf).